# Highstock candlestick chart wrong color

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/uVKNY/

look at the 3th candle, Open > Close, but candle is empty, why?
[1365870600000,3879.8,3879.8,3806.0,3860.0]

```
// create the chart
var data = [[1365867000000,3905.1,3943.7,3903.6,3903.9],[1365868800000,3903.8,3940.0,3804.0,3804.0],[1365870600000,3879.8,3879.8,3806.0,3860.0],[1365872400000,3920.0,3920.0,3859.0,3870.0],[1365874200000,3900.0,3900.0,3615.8,3852.0],[1365876000000,3702.1,3702.1,3502.0,3554.9],[1365906600000,3411.19,3472.54,3324.8,3400.0],[1365908400000,3460.0,3462.9,3400.0,3462.9],[1365910200000,3472.54,3498.58,3401.0,3498.0],[1365912000000,3420.0,3469.9,3400.0,3429.9],[1365913800000,3455.0,3467.0,3402.0,3466.0]];
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            type : 'candlestick',
            name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data : data,
            dataGrouping : {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You think it should be dark because the third close is lower than the third open.  But the logic is in fact "dark if close is lower than previous close."  See here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1395

Comment: On the real chart from btc-e it is dark:)